# Can mySQL find different things in the same query

Tags: mysql, multiple-columns

In this query which I got help from @jarlh, in this question [ORDER BY CASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53652527/sorting-table-by-different-cols-depending-on-what-happens-to-another-column)

```
SELECT *
FROM booking
WHERE booking_date=$b_date OR DATE(delivery_date)=$b_date
ORDER BY CASE WHEN booking_date=$b_date
                  THEN hour * 60 + minute
                  WHEN DATE(delivery_date)=$b_date
                  THEN HOUR(delivery_date) * 60 + MINUTE(delivery_date)
         END ASC
```

I need to find those posts with the same HOUR and MINUTE, before I leave the query, and mark them somehow, so I’m able to print them (those in the same hour and minute) horizontally and not vertically.

Comment: @AntG, I mean I need to use the same query as above, AND to be able to know which 2 or 3 posts have the same hour and minute, in the same query.
I know I can run several queries to achieve that, but that will make the whole page much slower to reload.

Comment: What happened to @AntG's comment? 
I answered it and it disappeared